# how to get acess to the input value that is selected

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error

```
error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:6:23)
```

Here is my code

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input[name="num"]:checked')


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(input.value)
    input.value = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML
    let before = document.getElementById('before')
    let after = document.getElementById('after')
    before.style.display = 'none'
    after.style.display = 'flex'
})
```

I am trying to do a challenge from Frontend Mentor, I need to get access to the input value that is checked, and this error is appearing, but I cannot find a solution

Comment: `how do a do`   For some reason that sounds like a fanatic jingle for a song.

Comment: sorry i wrote worng? english is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `null` is because `querySelector` didn't find a matching element, probably because you're looking for a checked input **too soon** (I'm guessing at page load). Instead, do your DOM query **inside** the `click` handler, so you're looking as of the click, not on page load.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Look for the checked input now that the button has been clicked
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name="num"]:checked');
    // *** Note the optional chaining (?.) on the below.
    // (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
    // That way, we get `undefined` instead of an error if no element matched
    // the selector.
    console.log(input?.value);
    /*
    input.value = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    let before = document.getElementById("before");
    let after = document.getElementById("after");
    before.style.display = "none";
    after.style.display = "flex";
    */
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="num" value="A"> A
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="num" value="B"> B
</label>
```